# Degeneracy and singularity of the $p$-laplace equation

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, p-laplace

In what sense is the $p$-Laplacian degenerate for $p$ greater than $2$ and singular for $p$ less than $2$?

Comment: I assume you should just look at the "directional derivative" $\frac{d}{dt} \Delta_p (f+tg)$. At the points where $\nabla f =0$, the expression you get is singular for $p<2$ and vanishes for $p>2$ (degenerate pointing at a vanishing of the derivative).

Comment: For a longer answer see math.stackexchange: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/306320/singularity-and-degeneracy-of-solution-to-p-laplace-equation